# Django URL use string in regex

Tags: python, regex, django, python-2.7, url

Currently my regex takes a question id like so (working):

```
url(r'^(?P<college_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name="detail")
```

But I want it to instead take `college_name` which is a string with no spaces. How would I set that up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `r'^(?P<college_name>\w+)/$'`

This is a great tool for testing regular expressions: https://regex101.com/r/q6fWPl/1